# When and how should I use "s'incruster"?

Tags: sens

I found this exchange on Quora

> Est-ce que les kangourous entrent dans les maisons en Australie ?
>
> Et puis, il n’y a pas que les kangourous qui essayaient de
> s’incruster…

I'm wondering what sort of register "s'incruster" belongs to.

Is it somewhat humorous, like "sneak into" in English (when talking about kangaroos)?

Thanks!

Comment: Familier. Prolonger à l'excès son séjour chez quelqu'un de façon inopportune : Il s'est incrusté et est resté tout le week-end ! To stick around, colloquially.

Answer (score 3):

The expression is slang, but not really humourous although it can be used in such a context.

Actually, it is often used as a negative. Say a friend just got dumped and he needs a little support and after 3 months he's still living in your spare room:

> « Il s'est incrusté dur là! »

The idea is that someone entered somewhere and stayed when not invited to do so for so long. In this case, “dur” (hard) suggests that he stuck around.

The first meaning of *incruster* is *inlay* (as in art, as in digging a small hole to place a jewel on a crown).

"sneak into" is certainly a good translation for an animal, especially since in such cases it is not likely to bother you on purpose (unintentional) and also those animals are probably not going to stay for long.

Comment: *sneak into* is more like "s'introduire".

Comment: @XouDo Il y a aussi "sneak into your business", qui peut être vu comme étant proche de "s'incruster".

Comment: The other "guest" was a [koala](https://fr.quora.com/Est-ce-que-les-kangourous-mettent-leur-mains-dans-leurs-poches).

Comment: @AlexisWilke Ah oui, dans ce sens là, ce serait plutôt *s'immiscer dans les affaires de quelqu'un*, *se mêler des affaires de quelqu'un*.

Comment: to stick around [too long] He really stuck around there.

Comment: Regarding the edit, I think that's what you meant. Feel free to modify it again.

Answer (score 3):

S’incruster quelque part, c’est entrer quelque part sans y être invité.
To gatecrash somewhere.

Comment: You may also be invited for one or two nights... not 3 months.

Comment: It is not gatecrash. Sorry.